# ESXi 4 failed to find boot device

Tags: boot, vmware-esxi, installation, failed

I had exsi 3.5 running just fine, the upgrade to 4 failed ( i thought it would so everything is backed up ). but it did boot just could not import the data store

So i did a fresh install of ESXi 4. Now it says failed to find boot device.

Not sure why. i have wiped the disk, the controller is a adaptec 3405, it worked fine in 3.5 and when i upgrade to 4 it did boot.

Now it just hangs at loading vfat. then the failed to find boot device.

Any ideas?

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Answer (score 1):

After getting ESXi 4 installed on a flash device i was still not able to create a datastore on the array. After searching around i found that disabling : Intel VT for direct in the BIOS cleared up the problems.

Probably disabling this from the start would have not had to do the reinstall

Comment: That's REALLY wierd, normally you'd WANT VT enabled - are you sure all your components are on the v4 HCL?

Comment: Agreed - much to my chagrin, a bunch of devices were dropped off the HCL in the ESXi v4.

Comment: Is that really VT that is disabled? Or VT for Directed IO (VT-d)? Since it is a drive issue, I'm willing to bet that it is a Directed IO problem.